# Product Type for hotel booking ticket in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, product-type

I have started to develop a website that is based on hotel booking. It requires to book ticket with adult/child price.

I am confused that which type of product I should use. It is simple or bundled product? Since ticket is not a real product that can be seen but a virtual ticket that is sold online to book hotel.

Can somebody give light on this?

Comment: as you mentioned in your post, it should be **virtual type**

Answer (score 0):

There're couple of extension available for this.

https://store.magenest.com/magento-2/booking-and-reservation.html
https://store.webkul.com/magento2-booking-reservation.html

If you are not willing to use any 3rd party extension you can create new product type.

https://www.classyllama.com/blog/custom-product-types-magento-2

Comment: I was asking product type that Magento provides.

Comment: You can use built in virtual type module with customizations as per your need.